# Inside Aurelia Dialog response, jquery is not working.

Tags: jquery, aurelia

I have one input file , with style "display:none", and a button, that trigger the input file element, according with some logic. Everything works OK, until I have to open a dialog, inside of the dialog,If  the user choose OK, I have  open the input file dialog, but it does not work. ¿how can I implemented this , when the user already has choose the answer in the dialog ?

```
<input type="file" style="display:none" class="file-input" id="files" 
ref="fileInput" change.trigger="processFile()"/>

<button type="submit" id="uploadButton" class="btn btn-default" 
click.delegate="openFileInput()" > Submit Selected </button>

 openFileInput()
 {
        if(somelogic){
            $("#files").click(); //here works cool
        }else
        {

            this.dialogService.open( {viewModel: Prompt, model: 'you  have alredy pickup a file, do you want t overrride it?',lock:false }).whenClosed(response => {                   
                 if (!response.wasCancelled) {   
                    $("#files").click();    //this not,             
                    setTimeout(() => {                       
                        $("#files").click();    //also if we wait, 3 seconds afther the dialog is closed.                    
                    },3000);
                    return;
                 } else {
                    console.log('cancelled');                    
                    return;
                 }
                 console.log('output ');                    
                 console.log(response.output);
              });
        }                  
 }
```

Comment: do you get anything output to console from your log statements within `.whenClosed()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try storing the `$("#files")` element as a variable before calling any function on it.

```
const filesInput = $("#files")
```

And then doing the following:

```
 openFileInput()
 {
        const filesInput = $("#files");
        if(somelogic){
            filesInput.click();
        }else
        {

            this.dialogService.open( {viewModel: Prompt, model: 'you  have alredy pickup a file, do you want t overrride it?',lock:false }).whenClosed(response => {                   
                 if (!response.wasCancelled) {   
                    filesInput.click();             
                    setTimeout(() => {                       
                        filesInput.click();
                    },3000);
                    return;
                 } else {
                    console.log('cancelled');                    
                    return;
                 }
                 console.log('output ');                    
                 console.log(response.output);
              });
        }                  
 }
```

**Edit:** I also recommend using Aurelia binding instead of JQuery. If you add `ref="files"` to your HTML element, and then add a field `public files: HTMLElement` to your viewmodel, you can reference the element in your methods without using JQuery.

**Edit 2:** If that does not work for you, try hiding the element using the following instead of `display: none`:

```
height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
visibility: hidden;
width: 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully understand what is the question but when the callback of `.whenClosed` is called the dialog is already detached(removed from the DOM) and unbound. If the markup is in the dialog then you will have to implement your logic in the dialog VM.

Comment: Please check the code, if you see, $("#files").click(); is working outside of whenClosed, but when calling inside of whenclosed is not work. how can i can execute this line -$("#files").click();- when the dialog is alredy closed ?